# PHP - Reorganizing an array into another array

Tags: php, html, arrays, sorting, indexing

I have this array:

```
Array ( [7] => 44 [6] => 45 [4] => 46 [1] => 47 [2] => 48 [8] => 49 [5] => 50 [3] => 51 )
```

I would like to create another array (or organize this one) so that I get the following array:

```
Array ( [1] => 47 [8] => 49 [2] => 48 [7] => 44 [3] => 51 [6] => 45 [4] => 46 [5] => 50 )
```

Basically:

```
[Lowest index] => [Highest index]
[Second lowest index] => [Second highest index]
[Third lowest index] => [Third highest index]
[Fourth lowest index] => [Fourth highest index]
```

And I need this reorganization to be automatic and to work with different sized arrays.

Comment: So have you tried coding anything yourself? Ot is this simply a "give me the codez" request?

Comment: Sorry, to me it unclear according to what rules exactly that new array should be constructed. Please try to be more specific.

Comment: You'll have to better explain what it is you're trying to do. Your question doesn't quite add up.

Comment: I'm making a website that generates tables for Round Robin tournaments. The array I showed above is the group of teams that will be in the tournament. The indexes are the seeds of each team, the values 44 to 51 are the IDs of the teams. In the first round, the team with the seed 1 plays against the team with the seed 8, round 2 is 2 agains 7, round 3 is 3 against 6 etc...It would be easier to have the array organized so that [1] is the seed 1 and [2] is the seed 8, [3] is seed 2 and [4] is seed 7, etc..

Comment: Alright, I get what you're looking for. However, this isn't possible in PHP because numeric keys in arrays cannot be rearranged. You would need to name your keys something like `"seed_1"` and `"seed_8"`, at which point you could sort the array and then write logic that reorders the elements as you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if anyone here is going to write your code for you. People like to see you making your own effort and then asking when you run into problems.

But to point you in the right direction: Look up the [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) functions. Then use them to split your array, and sort the two arrays (one containing the keys, one containing the values). Finally, combine your arrays again as desired with [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's done. This is what I did:

```
$arrayPos1 = array();
$posi = 3;
$parti = 2;

//Building first array with seeds 1, 3, 5 and 7
$arrayPos1[1] = $arrayPart[1];
for($i=1;$i <= (count($arrayPart) / 2 - 1);$i++){
    $arrayPos1[$posi] = $arrayPart[$parti];
    $posi = $posi + 2;
    $parti = $parti + 1;
}
$arrayPos2 = array();
$posi = 2;
$parti = count($arrayPart);

//Building second array with seeds 2, 4, 6 and 8
for($i=1;$i <= (count($arrayPart) / 2 );$i++){
    $arrayPos2[$posi] = $arrayPart[$parti];
    $posi = $posi + 2;
    $parti = $parti - 1;
}

//Checking out the results
print_r($arrayPos1);
echo "<br>";
ksort($arrayPos2);
print_r($arrayPos2);
echo "<br>";

//Building final array
for($i=2;$i <= (count($arrayPart));$i=$i+2){
    $arrayPos1[$i] = $arrayPos2[$i];
}

//Sorting final array
ksort($arrayPos1);
```

This should make generating the tables easier now.
Thanks for the help guys :)